# Teleport to next player

Tags: java, bukkit

I am working on a Spigot 1.8.9 plugin and am trying to add a feature when a staff right-clicks an item it teleports them to the next player that isn't in vanish and not themselves and if there aren't any it should return null.

On click I attempted to add all possible users to a list using

```
public static List<User> getPossibleUsers(User user){
    List<User> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(User target : users)
        if(!target.isVanished() && !user.getUUID().equals(target.getUUID()))
            result.add(target);
    return result;
}
```

The staff is also assigned an int called `nextPlayer` which is set to 0 when they login. Then when they click I add one to the int so next time they click it can get the next user.

```
private User getNextPlayer(User user) {
    int next = user.nextPlayer;
    List<User> users = getPossibleUsers(user);
    if(users.size() == 0)
        return null;
    int current = 0;
    for(User target : users) {
        if(current == next){
           return target;
        }
        current++;
    }
    user.nextPlayer = next;
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to make the getNextPlayer method correctly and make it efficient. I also would like to also to make it so once it hits the last player it loops back to the first player.

Comment: What is a User? to my knowledge that class doesn't exist under Spigot, only SpongeAPI, unless it's a class of your own creation.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach It's a custom object class that extends off Player to store extra data in this case if the user is vanished and an int to keep their place.

Comment: I'm going to assume you don't actually mean 'extending' player as in inheritance.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach oh yeah, no I mean as in when the object is created it saves the player and then I use methods off that player object.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest thinking about your problem entirely differently if you want it to be efficient, but efficiency really isn't a concern in this situation, so I'm opting to not pre-maturely optimize and instead work with the code you already have.

```
public static List<User> getPossibleUsers(User user){
    List<User> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(User target : users)
        if(!target.isVanished() && !user.getUUID().equals(target.getUUID()))
            result.add(target);
    return result;
}
```

This currently returns the Users in the same order, as they are defined on users.

This better have a natural sort order, otherwise you are going to have issues when people join / leave the server, as it will cause people to change their ordering in the list.

Now let's get back to first principals.

```
    int next = user.nextPlayer;
```

Looks like you are storing the index of the player in the list you have already been in on the 'user'.

Once you have this, you can access that index directly from the list.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-

`E get(int index)`

So, doing `users.get(next++);` is all you need to do to 'fix' the code you have above. it increments next, and gets the user at that position (assuming the ordering is consistent, and hasn't changed) However, it may throw an exception if it's out of range of the list, so we wrap it in

```
if(next <= users.length) {
    users.get(next++);
} else return null;
```

This will change it to returning null, if it would otherwise throw an exception.

**BUT** all of this still has a fatal flaw, that if the list is mutated between calls, that you could be potentially skipping or changing the order around.

A far better solution to this, is to instead cache the visited users, as well as the last visited user.

If the users are ordered, and you store the last visited user, instead of the index, you are storing data that is much more resilient to change, and more closely matches the behavior you want.

To more closely match your needs, you are asking that.

1. Generate a predictable, ordered list of users that don't include the admin, or anyone else that is vanished, to aid the admin in predicting where they are going.
2. Rotate through this list, by right clicking with a tool, (Note this is async, so all the state needs to be saved)
3. Ensure that all visited users are visited before repeating the sequence.

```
public class TeleportTooldata {
    private ListIterator<UUID> cursor;
    private List<UUID> cachedOrder;

    public TeleportTooldata(List<UUID> applicableUsers) {
        cachedOrder = applicableUsers;
    }

    @Nullable
    public UUID next() {
        if (!cursor.hasNext()) return null;
        UUID next = cursor.next();
        if (!cachedOrder.contains(next)) {
            cachedOrder.add(next);
        }
        return next;
    }

    public void Update(List<UUID> applicableUsers) {
        applicableUsers.removeAll(cachedOrder);
        cachedOrder.addAll(applicableUsers);
    }
}

public class TeleportToolUtil {
    YourPluginUserRepo repo;
    Map<User, TeleportTooldata> storage; //This could be a cache, make sure to remove if they log out, or maybe timed as well.

    public List<UUID> getApplicableUsers() {
        return repo.getOnlineUsers().stream()
                .filter(User::isVanish)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getId)) // You can change the sort order
                .map(User::getId)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void onToolUse(User user) {
        TeleportTooldata data = storage.computeIfAbsent(user, x -> new TeleportTooldata(getApplicableUsers()));
        UUID next = data.next();
        if (next == null) {
            data.Update(getApplicableUsers());
            next = data.next();
                if(next == null) {
                storage.put(user, new TeleportTooldata(getApplicableUsers()));
                next = data.next();
            }
        }
        user.teleportTo(next);
    }
}
```

A few changes.

1. We are now caching the ordering, so that you could conceptually also let the user go backwards through the list.
2. We are using ListIterator. ListIterator is an object that loops through lists, and stores the current position for you! Much like you were doing before, but without indexes.
3. We now have the possibility to update the data, in case a player joins late, or someone unvanishes they will be put at the back of the list if they are not already inside it.
4. when we run out of users, we attempt an update, if we are really out, we start again with a brand new list. (note this won't guarantee the same order every time (people will be 'properly' sorted when it updates if they were previously appended, but it's close enough for this usecase)

However! We still need to be mindful of memory leaks. using UUID's rather then players or users, means this class is very light weight, we should be pretty safe from memory leaks in the list of UUID AS LONG as the TeleportTooldata doesn't live too long.

You can replace the Map of TeleportTooldata with a cache (maybe from Guava?) to remove the data some time after the admin leaves the game.

If TeleportTooldata was expected to be long-lived, we would want to seriously consider removing UUID's from the history.

Also, not handled in my example, is the possibility of the users going offline after the order is cached.

To handle this, before teleporting the player, check if the uuid is online, otherwise go to the 'next' and follow all the same logic again.

Comment: Edit: accidentally left in visitedUsers even though it wasn't used any more, and never initially populated.